# Adding a character element to a numerical matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix, character

I have a 2 x 30 matrix in `R` consisting of 1s and 2s. I was wondering how I could add an additional `"p:"` before each element of my matrix?

For example, `p1: 1, p2: 2, p3: 1, p4: 2` and so on.

Here is what I tried with no success:

```
a <- matrix(rep(1:2, 30), 2, 30)
a <- paste0("p", 1:30, ":")
```

Comment: You'll want to use a `data.frame` since matrices only support numerics.

Comment: Try `a[] <- paste(paste0("p", 1:30), a, sep=": ")`

Comment: Simpler than `paste`? `sprintf("p%d: %d", 1:30, a)`.

Comment: I guess @akrun has it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `paste` 'p' with the sequence and then `paste` that with the `matrix` 'a' and assign the output back to the 'a'

```
a[] <- paste(paste0("p", 1:30), a, sep=": ")
```

Comment: I guess you could assign to any variable with `matrix(paste(paste0("p", 1:30), a, sep=": "), nrow = nrow(a))`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using apply:

```
apply(a, 2, function(x) paste('p', parent.frame()$i[], ': ', x, sep=''))
```